# How to use "edit" command via telnet

Tags: windows-xp, editing, command-line, telnet

I use telnet to connect my client, and try to edit a file. But I find that I can't edit it. I can't even use "Alt" key to control the application. How can I solve this problem? (I can't install any program on the client.)

(Windows 7 telnet to Windows XP. )

Comment: I guess the question is why are you using telnet? Even though the reason for your use of telnet is good, there may be a different way to edit files.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the fine text editing facilities that Microsoft has included with XP.  That means edlin.

Answer (score 0):

Try PSExec to run processes on the remote machine:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Telnet daemon that comes with Windows, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key should be mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.